# makefile (link 2 source files non is main)

Tags: c, makefile

I have a project that contains 4 source files :
   RTP.c, RTCP.c RTSP.c main.c 
and 3 header files : 
  RTP.h RTCP.h RTSP.h
I have to include all the header files in the main and the RTCP.h in the RTP.c after I included the header files in the source files I linked them in a make file please help me understand the problem.
the RTP.c

```
    #include "RTP.h"
    #include "RTCP.h"
```

the RTCP.c

```
    #include "RTCP.h"
```

The RTSP.c

```
    #include "RTSP.h"
```

The main.c

```
    #include "RTP.h"
    #include "RTSP.h"
```

The make file:

```
    OBJS = main.o RTPfunctions.o RTCPfunctions.o RTSPfunctions.o
    CC = gcc
    CCFLAGS  = -g

   Client : $(OBJS)
         $(CC) $(OBJS) -o -pthread client

   RTCPfunctions.o : RTCPfunctions.c RTCPfunctions.h
         $(CC) -c -g -pthread RTCPfunctions.c

   RTSPfunctions.o : RTSPfunctions.c RTSPfunctions.h
        $(CC) -c -g  -pthread RTSPfunctions.c

   RTPfunctions.o : RTPfunctions.c RTPfunctions.h RTCPfunctions.h
       $(CC) -c -g -o -pthread RTPfunctions.c RTCPfunctions.o

   main.o : main.c RTPfunctions.h RTSPfunctions.h
      $(CC) -c  -g -o -pthread main.c RTPfunctions.o RTSPfunctions.o

   clean:
     \rm *.o *~ client
```

Comment: How about `$(CC) $(OBJS) -o client -pthread`? and simmilar for all other cases.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Just add to what Mr. @Eregrith said, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very verbose, however, from a quick glance at your makefile, we can say, as per the [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options),

> `-o file`
>
> Place output in file `file`. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.

Basically, this says, the immidiate next argument to `-o` should be the output file name.

Also, to follow the [order of linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options), the `pthread` library should be placed at the end, like

```
 $(CC) $(OBJS) -o  client -pthread
```